# Dicas para otimizar o Select no SQL. A ordem das condicionais no Where importa?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, otimização

vocês tem alguma dica para otimização do Select no sql? 
Se eu fizer uma busca em uma tabela com mais de 500 mil ou 1 milhão de registros, há alguma forma de otimizar minha busca para que ela não gaste muitos recursos do servidor e nem demore muito?

A ordem que eu coloco as condicionais após o WHERE faz alguma diferença? 
Por exemplo, se eu coloco primeiro IDusuario=$idusuario (isso já reduziria bastante os registros), e então coloco Valor>50. Isso seria melhor do que colocar Valor>50 primeiro (que ainda geraria muitos registros) e em seguida o IDUsuario=$idusuario? Ou não faz diferença a ordem que se coloca as condicionais?

Enfim, se alguém puder dar algumas dicas de como otimizar, eu agradeceria muito! Inclusive no tipo de tabela, usar MyISAM ou InnoDB no BD MySql. Obrigado!

Comment: Crie indices para otimizar a busca. Uma dica, seria usar as ferramentas do do Oracle ou SQL-Server para otimizar o seu select. Elas sugerem a criação dos indices faltantes. A ordem das colunas na clausula WHERE não importam.